# Can I say "Allah laughs"?

Tags: halal-haram, allah

Does ALLAH laugh on situations where a human laughs? Like does ALLAH laugh at something funny which happens in the human world?

Comment: It has been edited now.

Answer (score 1):

**Allah, Exalted He is, Laughs, His laughter isn't like any of His creation, and as how appropriate for His glory.**

It is not like laughing at funny incidents we face in life, rather the narrated hadeeth that described Allah as laughing are few.

> Narrated / Authority Of: Waki bin Hudus that his paternal uncle Abu
>   Razin said: “The Messenger of Allah (saw) said: 'Allah laughs at the
>   despair of His slaves although He soon changes it.' I said: 'O
>   Messenger of Allah, does the Lord laugh?' He said: 'Yes.' I said: 'We
>   shall never be deprived of good by a Lord Who laughs.'” (Hasan)

Also you can find another example in Sahih Bukhary and Muslim.

> It has been narrated on the authority of Abu Huraira that the
>   Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said:
>
> God laughs at the two men both of whom will enter Paradise (though)
>   one of them kills the other. They said: Messenger of Allah, how is it?
>   He said: One of them fights in the way of Allah, the Almighty and
>   Exalted. and dies a martyr. Then God turns in mercy to the murderer
>   who embraces Islam, fights in the way of Allah, the Almighty and
>   Exalted, and dies a martyr.
>   Sahih Muslim 1890

And Allah knows best.